# Can the server specify that the client use GET or POST or other method request the redirected url?

Tags: http, web

I think it is can't !
But my boss think it is can, i don't know how to do!

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

The server can specify whether the method should be the same as for the original request URI, or whether POST can be changed to GET. See RFC 7231 for the details.

Comment: how specify? state is 300~307?

Comment: See RFC 7231 for details.